# How can i send a form directly to an email?

Tags: html, email

How can I insure the form I created will be send directly to my email after I click on "send"? Because now after I click on "send" it takes me directly to a new message on my Gmail screen, with the same information as in the form.

So now I first have to click on the first button (send) and after that I have to click on the second button of my email.

How can I avoid this, and make sure it will send the info directly to my email after pressing the first button?

This is a part of my code:

```
<form action="mailto:random@gmail.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
<em>user name</em></br>
<input type="text" size="25" name="user name" class="auto-clear" placeholder="user Name"><p /><br>
<em>Email</em></br>
<input type="text" size="25" name="email" class="auto-clear" placeholder="email"><p /><br>
<em>how many extra pages</em><br>
<select name="extra pages">
<option>0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select><br><br>
<em>Did we helped you?</em><br>
<input type="radio" name="Did we helped you" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="Did we helped you" value="No">No<br><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Send!">
</form>
```

Comment: use any server script (php, asp) to pass form data to email

Comment: And how do i do that? I don't have any experience with php

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to look for a tutorial or example. There may be millions out there by now.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer** - You can't avoid that just using HTML

**Long Answer** - 
What you are seeing is the pc setting of how to handle sending emails through the browser that are using just html.  Someone else could be having it load up an outlook message with your email in the to section.  To accomplish what you are stating requires server side coding.  That will ensure that when the user clicks on the send button, it can be programmed to just send.  Technically the user won't even know the email as sent successfully, unless you code it to notify them.